# Eclipse/Tomcat forgetting about custom tags?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, custom-tags

I'm using Eclipse Kepler with Tomcat 7 on Windows 7 64 bit.

If I clean the project and restart the server, everything works great. But if I work for a couple of minutes... like editing a jsp... Tomcat barfs up the following...

The tag it complains about missing is the tag for page layout. Nothing exciting there other than it does some jspf includes and the content pages also call other tags. But again, nothing exciting...

I don't see how I could be causing this as the thing compiles and runs fine initially. But then Tomcat seems to lose track of the tag classes.

If I clean the project, it goes back to working for a while...

Any ideas?
Thanks

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 33 in the jsp file: /folder/page.jsp
org.apache.jsp.tag.weblayout_002dmain_tag cannot be resolved to a type
30: 
31: 
32: 
33: <tags:layout-main>
34:     <jsp:attribute name="title">page</jsp:attribute>
35:     <jsp:attribute name="section">user</jsp:attribute>
36:     <jsp:attribute name="handle">page</jsp:attribute>


An error occurred at line: 33 in the jsp file: /folder/page.jsp
org.apache.jsp.tag.weblayout_002dmain_tag cannot be resolved to a type
30: 
31: 
32: 
33: <tags:layout-main>
34:     <jsp:attribute name="title">page</jsp:attribute>
35:     <jsp:attribute name="section">user</jsp:attribute>
36:     <jsp:attribute name="handle">page</jsp:attribute>


An error occurred at line: 106 in the jsp file: /folder/page.jsp
org.apache.jsp.tag.webrating_tag cannot be resolved to a type
103:            <div class="page clearfix">
104:                <div class="title">
105:                    <h3>${page.name}</h3>
106:                    <br><tags:rating value="${3}"/>                         
107:                    <br>${page.type}
108:                </div>
109:                <div class="hours">
```

Comment: Are you republishing to Tomcat after modifying code?

Comment: It is set to build automatically. And Tomcat is configured in Eclipse as a Server. I always assumed this means that Eclipse will look after it for me. If I copy all the files to a separate Tomcat server (hosted) it always works just fine. But Eclipse is messing it up somehow.

Comment: The TAG files that are getting lost are used all over the app. They are basically the HTML design template...

Comment: Iirc in the Server view in Eclipse there is a button "Pusblish to the server" that you need to click for changes to be correclty deployed.

Comment: I did have it set to publish automatically without prompting... For some time now Eclipse has been behaving like things are out of sync. I wonder if I should rebuild the environment from scratch? Though that may be how it started...

Comment: I'm a Java teacher and I've had that same problem for the last 3 years with the current version of Eclipse each year, with Tomcat 6 and 7, on several student machines and on mine. It happens once the project starts to have a reasonable size, this does not happen with hello world projects. We are typically using JPA/Hibernate 3/4, Spring 3, Spring MVC, JSPs, SVN. I think that the only plugin installed is subclipse. The first .tag file needed by a JSP triggers an exception. Need clean/restart.

Comment: Last info: it only happens if we change a file between the restarts. It does not matter if we stop the server before changing the files or not.

Comment: Would http://philip.yurchuk.com/2008/12/03/eclipse-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-error/ help?

Comment: @VonC no sorry. The problem does not seems to be bound to Eclipse > Project > Clean, but is bound to Server view > Tomcat > clean... I'm trying to do a video to show the problem but of course, I cannot make it fail while doing the video ... after it failed all the day today. I'll code tomorrow and try to identify some pattern when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try Any of the following, it should work

1. copy the jar in `WEB-INF/lib/` directory and then restart your web container
2. Try

   ```
   <%@ page language="java" import="Pkgname.className.*" %>
   ```

For example

```
    <%@ page language="java" import="org.apache.jsp.tag.webrating" %>
```

1. Clean Project and Restart Server